# Remove an enitre row on basis of it's index in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have total 97 rows on my page, I have to remove only those rows having class "*hidden*". I tried to do it with a for loop, but it gives me an error **Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tr "0"**. Please help.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('tr').length; i++) {
        if ($('tr "'+[i]+'" ').attr('class') == 'hidden') {
            $('tr').remove();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The reason it fails is you are looking for an element with an attribute of zero

AKA:

    `<tr 0=asdf/>`

You are not looking at index.

Comment: BTW if you already have class why not use CSS to accomplish the task? `.hidden {display: none;}`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following selector.

```
$('tr.hidden').remove();
```

Also I do recommend to [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).